# How to combine across, summarize, and n() in R to get number of non-NA values by column?

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize, across

I have a list of questions, and I want to know how many rows have non-NA values using summarize. I want to use summarize because I'm already using that to calculate the average, which works in the below code. Why does the below code not work and how can I fix it?

```
library(dplyr)

test <- tibble(student = c("j", "c", "s"),
               q1 = c(1, 2, 3),
               q2 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 4),
               q3 = c(43, NA_real_, 232))

test %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n = across(starts_with("q"), ~n(.x)),
                   avg = across(contains("q"), ~ round(mean(.x, na.rm = T), 2)))


expected_outcome <- tibble(n_q1 = 3,
                           n_q2 = 1,
                           n_q3 = 2,
                           avg_q1 = 2,
                           avg_q2 = 4,
                           avg_q3 = 138)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

test %>% 
  summarize(across(starts_with("q"), list(n = ~sum(!is.na(.)),
                                         avg = ~mean(., na.rm = T)),
                   .names = "{.fn}_{.col}"))
```

From the `?across` documentation, you can pass a list to the `.fns` argument:

> A list of functions/lambdas, e.g. list(mean = mean, n_miss = ~ sum(is.na(.x))

This will apply every function in that list to the columns you have specified. You can then use the `.names` argument of `across` to set the column names how you desire.

**Output**

```
   n_q1 avg_q1  n_q2 avg_q2  n_q3 avg_q3
  <int>  <dbl> <int>  <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
1     3      2     1      4     2   138.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Upps I missed the whole question. sorry: But here is an alternative just for fun: The preferred answer is already given by @LMc:

```
library(dplyr)

test %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with("q"), list(avg = ~mean(., na.rm = T)),
                   .names = "{.fn}_{.col}")) %>% 
  bind_cols(test %>% purrr::map_df(~sum(!is.na(.))))

  avg_q1 avg_q2 avg_q3 student    q1    q2    q3
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <int> <int> <int> <int>
1      2      4   138.       3     3     1     2
```

```
test %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with("q"), list(avg = ~mean(., na.rm = T)),
                   .names = "{.fn}_{.col}")) %>% 
  bind_cols(test %>% purrr::map_df(~sum(!is.na(.))))
```

**First not full answer:**
To get the non-nas of the whole dataset, we could do this:

```
library(dplyr)

test %>% 
  purrr::map_df(~sum(!is.na(.)))
```

```
 student    q1    q2    q3
    <int> <int> <int> <int>
1       3     3     1     2
```